# using rich textbox in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, richtextbox, sharepoint-2013, rich-text-editor

I want to use a rich textbox in Sharepoint 2013 as seen in the figure below. How can I do that?

[image: Sharepoint 2013 rich text editor]

I have already used the code below.

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

`<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="RichTextField1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" RichTextMode="FullHtml" Columns="20" Rows="10"/>`

but I could not get what I need. I got a simple multiline textbox with scroll.

Thank you for the answers.

[image]

Comment: Same question on SharePoint Stack Exchange, but no answers there, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124917/multiple-lines-of-text-rich-text-editor-not-working-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this in

```
RichText="true"
```

more or less it would be like this as a sample:

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="rftDefaultValue" 
RichText="true" 
RichTextMode="FullHtml" runat="server" 
TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5">
</SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>
```

also, if you're viewing this using chrome, it would only show as a plain text box, try viewing this using IE :)

Comment: Thank you.It worked in IE. what can I do to make it work in all browsers?

Comment: im not really sure, since even the normal rich text box of sharepoint doesn't work in chrome sadly.

Comment: anyone coming across this as of today should know that **Chrome** works with the Content Editor (at least in SharePoint 2010 - so 2013 should definitely work).

Answer (score 1):

Rich Text boxes are an old issue on non IE browsers, if you want to use the abilities of the rich text you will have to use IE.

You can implement other rich text editors on your sharepoint site like tinymce http://joshmccarty.com/2011/06/use-tinymce-as-the-rich-text-editor-in-sharepoint-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I have used this external (cross platform) content editor: http://nicedit.com/index.php and it worked perfectly for me.

And it looks like this:

[image]