# Sharepoint 2013 Limit editing to just text

Tags: css, sharepoint, text, editor, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to limit content editors on sites to just text? I would like to have them not inject any styles by using inline styling in HTML, or using any buttons in the editor.

I have a few *rogue* editors that go color and style crazy, and for the next iteration of the public facing site I run, I don't want any chance of that happening.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options I've used in the past - neither is ideal but they may help you.

1. You can disable features from the rich text editor. Read through this [article](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/consistent-content-authoring-sharepoint-2010-rich-text-editor/) - it should apply to SP 2013 the same but basically, you can disable color, font, etc from being applied in the RTE.
2. You can use jquery to remove all styles after the fact. `$("#element").removeAttr("style");`

Comment: I'd probably have to use both. The current CMS removes scripting, and I had people using JavaScript marquee scripts in the HTML editor. Thank you for the link to the article.

Comment: Another option may be to predefine what all of your `<h1>`, `<p>`, and any other tag selected from the RTE displays as. There is an SP prefix for all these tags that you can override with your CSS. Usually it's something like `.ms-rtestate-field h1` but there are quite a few variations you have to account for with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can accomplish this limitation using a content editor. According to Microsoft, content editor's are designed for HTML so any setting to disable HTML input would be counter intuitive.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/about-the-content-editor-web-part-HA001160897.aspx

"The Content Editor Web Part is intended for adding HTML content to a Web Part Page"

I'm not sure from your post what you are trying to accomplish holistically, or what business need these content editors solve. Could you build a static page/template that fits your need (and maybe even looks like the normal content editor) but utilizes the rich text box feature?

[using rich textbox in Sharepoint 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054020/using-rich-textbox-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: The RTE will allow the same color, font, etc choices at the CEWP. You want a (nonexistant) plain text editor.